# Thoughts on OCR Solutions for SharePoint?

Tags: recommendations

We are looking at implementing OCR solutions for our contracts management application; if you have implemented or evaluated any OCR solutions for SharePoint; please share your thoughts/opinions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a number of vendors that offer scan/OCR solutions that integrate with SharePoint including KnowledgeLake.

[KnowledgeLake Capture](http://www.knowledgelake.com/products/Pages/Document-Capture-for-SharePoint.aspx)

Comment: KnowledgeLake is rather expensive - like say, around $40,000.

Comment: True, but most of the vendor solutions in this area are designed for large companies that process thousands of documents a day. The performance and hardware integration required by the solutions is extensive, and is reflected in the price.

Comment: I will say that KnowledgeLake is *very* nice - better than any other solution I have reviewed.  But it better be if it costs that much!

Comment: How can I download this KnowledgeLake tool for demo?

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a very rare requirement so I don't think there is any readily available product. You can write your own [using c# and OCR libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/744966/any-open-source-c-ocr-library).

Answer (score 1):

Certain integration scenarios are also available from ABBYY such as FlexiCapture and Recognition Server: http://www.abbyy.com/data_document_capture/

Didn't have the chance to compare to KnowledgeLake.

Not affiliated. Worked a bit with the Recognition Server last year.